# How to find the third vertex of an isosceles triangle in python

Tags: python, math, geometry, triangulation

Given:

Base of the triangle.

Height of the triangle.

The x coordinates of the base vertices.

Isosceles angle which connects the base vertices to the third vertex.

How to find the third vertex?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about trigonometry not programming

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to write a code for finding the third vertex.

Comment: If you know the base and the x coordinate o the base then you can compute the x coordinate of the third vertex: leftmost x coordinate + base of triangle / 2. The y coordinate of the third vertex is the height. Try it on (graph) paper first, it should make sense pretty fast :)

Comment: But the triangle is not on the x axis. To the height something must be added to get the y-coordinate.

Comment: So your triangle is lying on the base (the base is parallel with the x plane in your coordinate system), right ?

Comment: yes :) I think this is where the angle would help, but I don't know how

Comment: If the base is parallel with the x axis then you can do exactly what George Profenza already said. You don't need to know the angles.

Comment: But my y coordinate will be the height+ something, no?
something= difference between the base and x-axis

Comment: You should break this problem in two parts. First, the math of it should be posted to math.stackexchange.com. Then if you're still struggling to implement that, you can post here here. Otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: Are you sure about the numbers you're given? For example, why would you need to be given both the base length and the two base x-coordinates? If the base is parallel to the x-axis, it should be trivial to compute the former from the latter. Maybe you're given the base y-coordindate as well? Otherwise, there's no way to compute that from the numbers given, and you have to assume it's 0.

Comment: Could you provide a picture for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Compute the 2D vector from one base vertex to the other. Rotate this vector by 60°, the rotation matrix being:

```
|cos(60)°   sin(60°)|
|sin(60°)  -cos(60°)|
```

Add the resulting vector to the first vertex.